# Auto type into form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, field

I have this input field :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lookup" placeholder=" Start typing:">
```

When a user starts typing something on the keyboard, the field should be automatically selected.
I can not find a way to do that.

Comment: There is only one input in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
  $('#lookup').focus();
});
```

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/ocINILiS/1/edit)**

If you want this NOT to trigger while other inputs have focus:

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
  var $focused = $('input:focus');
  if (!$focused.length) {
    $('#lookup').focus();
  }
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ocINILiS/8/edit)**

You could use the same logic to exclude anything else like a textarea:

```
var $focused = $('input:focus, textarea:focus');
```

Comment: If you got couple of inputs? :\

Comment: @justtal This is what he asked for. It could be expanded, but how should I know?

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive answer !

Comment: @Axxess np. Too bad someone downvoted it. I have no idea why.

Comment: @m59 i think i did that by mistake. Code works great just what i needed

Comment: @Axxess lollll. Well, it was for the best. I did make a slight mistake . I forgot the `var` keyword on `$focused`. I was just thinking...man someone's harsh for downvoting instead of just editing it =D